# flash an LED 1 to 3 short times in an intervall with arduino/c++

Tags: c++, arduino

I want to let an LED flash some times in an intervall, a lot like the good old BIOS-BEEPS, to give me visual feedback of the program-state and I already got my code working for 3 short flashes, but for every additional flash I have to add code manualy.

I think, there must be a better way, but I cant figure it out, because the functions must not using delays or looping while blinking and therefor stopping the rest of the programm...

Because I want to get better at programming, I want you to ask, what has the function to look like to be working without adding code every time?

Here is my code for 1 to 3 flashes, I cleaned it a bit up for you:

```
flag++ // gets incremented every 100ms by interrupt no matter what...

// function to flash an LED
// each flash should be 200ms long (2 increments of 'flag')
// 200ms LED on, 200ms LED off
// given is the number of flashes and the duration till it begins 
// to flash again. 
void blink(int how_many_times, int duration) {

  if (how_many_times >= 1) {  // blink once
    switch (flag) {
    case 2:  // 200ms
      LED_ON;
      break;
    case 4:
      LED_OFF;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (how_many_times >= 2) { // blink twice
    switch (flag) {
    case 6:
      LED_ON;
      break;
    case 8:
      LED_OFF;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (how_many_times >= 3) { // blink 3 times
    switch (flag) {
    case 10:
      LED_ON;
      break;
    case 12:
      LED_OFF;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(flag >= duration*10) { // *10 because duration is in 'seconds'
    flag=0;
  }
}

// to let it blink 3 times fast every 5 seconds:
blink(3, 5);
```

Comment: Just some clarification: It looks like this code is executed as an interrupt every 100ms, right?

Comment: Is the 'flag' variable only used for this?

Comment: (Also - why did you remove the 'C' tag? This looks like perfectly ordinary C to me.)

Comment: No, blink(); is called in the loop() without interrupt, only 'flag' gets incremented every 100ms per interrupt. Is this wrong?

Comment: 'flag' is only used for blink(), yes. And I didnt remove 'c', a moderator did.

Comment: @Popup: I did remove the tag, as OP clearly states in the title it is C++. He can rollback or re-add if he thinks different (but should remove the c++ tag then).

Comment: @Skimmy: Not a moderator, but me. These are different languages. As your title clearly state "C++", I assumed the C tag was added "just to be safe". Bad enough, but this is common practice by newbies (and low-rep posters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you would like to get better at programming, I would recommend starting by being more descriptive with your variables.  For example, `flag` doesn't really describe what that variable is doing.  It really resembles a timer, so why not call it `timer_100ms`?  Then you know exactly what that variable is for.

I would also recommend using an enumeration for `case` statements so that what you are trying to accomplish is a little more clear.  For example:

```
/* This timer is incremented every 100ms by the interrupt. */
int timer_100ms;

void blink (int how_many_times, int duration)
{
    enum
    {
        ELAPSED_TIME_200MS = 2,
        ELAPSED_TIME_400MS = 4,
        /* Fill in other values */
        ELAPSED_TIME_1200MS = 12
    };

    if (how_many_times >= 1)
    {
        switch (timer_100ms)
        {
            case ELAPSED_TIME_200MS:
                LED_ON;
                break;

            case ELAPSED_TIME_400MS:
                LED_OFF;
                break;
        }
    }

    /* The rest of your code follows... */
}
```

Doing this makes your code a lot more readable.

That being said, to make your code more scalable - with the ability to create more LED blinks without adding more code - I would recommend starting with something like the following:

```
void blink (int number_of_blinks, int delay_between_blinks_in_seconds)
{
    #define ELAPSED_TIME_200MS  2

    static int blink_count = 0;
    static int timer_prev_100ms = 0;

    /* If the delay has been satisfied, start blinking the LED. */
    if (timer_100ms >= (delay_between_blinks_in_seconds * 10))
    {
        /* Change the state of the LED every 200ms. */
        if ((timer_100ms - timer_prev_100ms) >= ELAPSED_TIME_200MS)
        {
            timer_prev_100ms = timer_100ms;

            if (led_is_on())
            {
                LED_OFF;
                blink_count++;
            }
            else
            {
                LED_ON;
            }
        }

        if (blink_count >= number_of_blinks)
        {
            timer_100ms      = 0;
            timer_prev_100ms = 0;
            blink_count      = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you would need to add the `led_is_on()` function to check the state of the pin you are using to flash the LED.  Since, I don't know how you have your LED wired, I didn't want to assume how that would be done.  It is very simple to implement though.

Comment: wow. Thank you very much for this extensive explanation and this very nice example of "how to do it better". I recognized, you do start reversed: With the whole time at first and then with the blinky stuff. All I imagined for myself began with blinky-stuff and THEN to wait for the pause - I think it changed the way I look at code now... Thank you!

Comment: I tried your code, cause it looked soooooo promising, but now the LED is flashing twice and the third time it keeps staying on. I called it with "blink(3, 5);" Got to look out for the little error...

Comment: @Skimmy, I think it is because I forgot to reset the `blink_count`... I've updated my code in the answer.